# Convergence for $\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n\left(\ln n\right)\ln(\ln n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am not allowed to use the integral test. Basically I need to find whether this is convergent or not.
$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n\left(\ln n\right)\ln(\ln n)}$$

I tried using Bertrand's test since it seemed like it would be a good fit here but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: If can'r use Integral Test, try the Cauchy Condensation Test. You will have to apply it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. You may have a look at the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). Apply it twice as noticed by @André Nicolas.